# Composing an immutable list by 'foreach' over a List[JsObject]

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I have a List[JsObject] named myobj.

I want to create a new List by 'foreaching' over the first list. Something like this:

```
val newList = List.apply(
  myobj.foreach({
  d => val art = d.as[Article]
  return art 
  })
)
```

The idea being that for each JsObject in myobj the val 'art' is computed and returned to the apply method of List to then build up the newList.

This doesn't compile. 
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `map` instead of `foreach` for this:

```
val newList = myobj.map(_.as[Article])
```

Comment: @sectornitad FYI there is a whole pile of convinient methods, like `filter`, `collect`, `distinct`, `sorted`, `drop`, `exists` and so on.  To digest them, take a look to [List doc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List) (scroll down), for example, click on `def blahblah` to get detailed info.

Comment: Keep in mind that using the `as` method is an unsafe Reads operation that will throw an error if the read fails.  `asOpt` or `validate` are safer